# Attachments uploading is not working with osTicket

Tags: attachment

I'm trying to set up osTicket (http://osticket.com/) on my server, and everything is fine except for uploading attachments or emailing attachments while opening a new ticket. I've set the attachments settings correctly, as I can send a reply to a ticket with an attachment through the Staff account and it appears correctly in my attachments folder on the server, but when I try to email an attachment or upload an attachment while opening a new ticket, the ticket gets opened without any errors but there is no attachment along with it. How do I fix this? Please help!

P.S. I know all about osTicket's attachment vulnerabilities, and I will mitigate that by disallowing outside access to my server's attachment folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Attachements from some senders just disappeared. I changed the email settings to fetch using POP instead of IMAP. After that, it worked OK.

Hope this will help you too.